# Circular view path Spring boot tutorial

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm actually learning Spring Boot. I follow the guides and i'm tryng this one : Securing a Web Application.

So I've made 2 files (hello.html/home.html) and i would like to deploy my application to see them but when i try to access localhost:8080 i get this error :

```
Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/home] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

If someone can help me there ? Here is my code :

src/main/java/com/society/MyApplication :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(CalamarApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

src/main/java/com/society/MvcConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

src/main/resources/templates/home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: See this post -- we need more info about your controllers to diagnose.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113452/circular-view-path-in-a-simple-spring-boot-project-with-a-controller